# POSTing an entity type with children to an (MVC Web Api) OData service

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've been looking around for an answer to the following questions, but have so far not found one.

1. Does the OData standard support doing a POST request containing an entity object with child entity objects?
2. If so, does the ASP.NET MVC Web Api OData framework (`EntitySetController`) support this out of the box?

The scenario I have in mind goes something like the following. You have a `Parent` object, containing several `Child` objects. Could you then do a POST with a body like this?

```
{ "Property1" : "Property value", "Property2" : 100 
     "Children" : [
          { "ChildProperty" : "Some value" },
          { "ChildProperty" : "Some other value" },
          { "ChildProperty" : "Some third value" }
     ]
}
```

Also, if I later would like to add another child to the `Parent` object through POSTing a single child, is there a standardized way of linking them together? Something like

```
 { "ChildProperty" : "Fourth child property val", "Parent" : 321 }
```

where '321' is the ID of the parent object?

Many thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Can you share the URL as well where you would want to POST the payload?

Comment: Well, since it is a hypothetical example, I don't have an actual URL, but I suppose it would be something like www.mysite.com/odata/parents. I.e. the same URL where I would POST a new Parent object without children (which works just fine already).

Comment: I was initially confused when you said complex object. You should ideally call it entity object as only entities in OData are directly addressable. I added an answer below.

Comment: I see. That mix-up of terms might explain why I couldn't find anything on Google either. I'll update my question so as not to confuse future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, OData supports this and web API OData supports it as well. OData calls it `deep insert`. Here is the link to the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/cs01/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-cs01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc365046309).

Now there can be two types of deep inserts,

1) The nested item is new as well and should be created. An example of the json payload looks like this,

```
{
    ‘Property1’: 42,
    ‘Property2’: ‘Contoso’,
    ‘Children’: [
    {
        ‘ChildProperty’: 1,
        ……….
    },
    {
        ‘ChildProperty’: 2,
        ……….
    }]
}
```

2) The nested items already exist, the parent item is new and must be linked to the nested items. OData protocol calls this bind. Sample payload looks like,

```
{
    ‘Property1’: 42,
    ‘Property2’: ‘Contoso’,
    ‘Children@odata.bind’: [
        “http://localhost/Children(1)”,
        “http://localhost/Children(2)”,
    ]
}
```

Web API OData supports first kind of deep inserts and doesn't have support for binds (the second example). In case of the first payload, your controller would receive a `Parent` object with the `Children` collection properly populated.

And regarding your second question, you have two options,

1) POST the child to `~/Parents(321)/Children` URL

2) POST the child to `~/Children` and then POST the ID link of this child from this response to the URL `~/Parents(321)/$links/Children`.

You could refer to this [link](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/cs01/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-cs01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc365046313) for this part of the OData spec.

Comment: Thank you! In regards to the latter answer, part 1), I suppose the relevant action method would be named according to convention. Would the method in this case be 'PostChildren(int key, Child entity){...}' with the HttpPost attribute?

Comment: I found the answer to my question here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/457028. You have been busy. ;) Still, without support for binding through links it seems quite hard to accomplish anything more complex. Any insight on if/when such support can be expected in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Has binding support been added to Web API yet?