# Insert 2 entity value in odata in single post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

i have a two entity

```
Public Class Order
{
Public int Id{get;set;}
public string Name{get; set;}
public List<OrderDetail> {get;set;}
}

Public Class OrderDetail
{
Public int Id{get;set;}
public string Item{get;set;}
public float Amount{get;set;}

public int Order{get;set;
}
```

and i create asp.net webapi Odata service 
and i want to insert both table data in single post request

Answer (score 2):

Batch is a fine suggestion, as is deep insert. See [POSTing an entity type with children to an (MVC Web Api) OData service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130441/posting-an-entity-type-with-children-to-an-mvc-web-api-odata-service) for more details on using deep insert with Web API OData